# My returned data is not gzipped with connect.compress()

Tags: javascript, node.js, gzip, node.js-connect

I am trying to use the `connect.compress()` middleware to gzip my responses to the client. I am able to partially get it to work but when I add my own response using `res.end` the response is no longer gzipped.

Gzipped responses:

```
app = connect()
      .use(connect.compress())
      .use(connect.query())
      .use(connect.json());
```

Not gzipped responses:

```
app = connect()
      .use(connect.compress())
      .use(connect.query())
      .use(connect.json())
      .use(function (req, res) {
        res.end('hello');
      });
```

**I would like to be able to respond with my own message but still have the content gzipped.**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with small HTTP response bodies.  If the Content-Length of the response body < compress' threshold value (default is 1024 bytes), then the response will **not** be compressed, with no warning (see [the source code](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/compress.html)).

The solution is disable the threshold.

```
app.use(connect.compress({ threshold: false }));
```

As a new player to Connect I would expect that APIs would document what default values would be in place (ie: not specifying a threshold value default to 1024 bytes).  Personally I think that not specifying a threshold should default it to 0; I don't want a threshold otherwise I'd specify it in the config.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

`res.end('hello');`

with this:

```
res.end(new Buffer('hello', 'utf8'));
```

If that works, it's probably a bug in your version of the connect middleware.