# Node.JS deflate/gzip response text

Tags: javascript, node.js

I saw the example shown [here](http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_examples)

```
response.writeHead(200, { 'content-encoding': 'deflate' });
raw.pipe(zlib.createDeflate()).pipe(response);
```

I tried to send the response by creating a read stream and sending deflated output.

But I am looking for a way to do it without read stream, because the text I have comes from another `HTTP` request. I simply used to `response.write(text);`

I tried a couple of things including

```
zlib.deflate(text, function (err, buffer) {
    if (err) throw err;
    response.write(buffer);
    response.end();
});
```

But the browser says `invalid or unsupported form of compression.`

What am I doing wrong?

`connect`'s code says

```
return stream
    ? stream.write(new Buffer(chunk, encoding))
    : write.call(res, chunk, encoding);
```

So is it like only streams will be processed?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Express? If so, just use the `compress` middleware:

```
app.use(express.compress());
```

http://expressjs.com/api.html#compress

Comment: No, I am using `connect`, and trying to compress in `router` function. Any other idea?

Comment: using `connect.compress` I have same problem he is facing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163393/my-returned-data-is-not-gzipped-with-connect-compress

Comment: See my new answer on the above question.

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to solve the problem. Here is the code

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
var connect = require('connect');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = connect()
    // .use(connect.compress()) It didn't work either
    .use(function (req, res, next) {
        var text = fs.readFileSync('test.js');

        zlib.deflate(text, function (err, buffer) {
            if (err) throw err;

            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Encoding': 'deflate',
                'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'
            });

            res.end(buffer);
        });
    })
    .listen(1337);
```

I don't know what mistake I did earlier causing it not to work. I am not sure if any version conflict was causing the problem or something else. but finally, the above code works for me ;)

Comment: that is a horrible solution because you are storing the entire file in memory

Comment: Well, I am aware and was only doing it for some testing purpose. However, request you to post any better solution if you have, so others can get benefit from best practice. Thanks.

Comment: `res.writeHead(); fs.createFileStream(file).pipe(zlib.createGzip()).pipe(res));`

Comment: Of course, Its there in the `node.js` documentation. I thought you have some other way of doing this.
consider the case, where its not a file read operation and you are getting the data from an `HTTP` stream, or may be its an output of a `child_process`, how would you deflate that data?

Comment: you mean like a client request, then piping the response through your server? for that you would do the same thing, except you have to handle the content encodings.

Comment: `child_process.stdout.pipe(zlib.createGzip()).pipe(res)`. same thing, assuming you're using spawn and not exec.

Comment: I am getting the data through solr by `client.get(solrQuery, callback);`, so the result is coming as function parameter in the callback. in that case how do I `pipe` the output?

Comment: You can't pipe it unless the response is a stream

Comment: Ok, Thanks. so for that `zlib.deflate(text, callback);` would be efficient I think. with some caching technology whenever possible for avoiding overhead of deflating.