# How to decode deflate string in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, zlib, deflate

I am using nodejs to build an app which consumes some external API which returns json data compressed in deflate format but since I am new to nodejs so I have had a look on zlib api but did not find a way to decode the string, 
Please anyone help me out, here is my decoded string:

```
u�O��0\u0010ſJ�CN4��?RT���ޫʚ�\u0001����f)]��wذڪ�r��7�͓�W�\u0003���?_�\u0005T����\tT����\u000f����y=��cu\u0012��\u000e����A��,5�\u0005\u0017ER�\u0011�^�8\rvE��0x��\u0000>��*�jTRA�\\SQe)/�d�����C�<?�4��4\u0007\b�\u001a��`(��@Y��\u0011{���-j���ք�\u0013� ^Y��T��\u001f��\u0010y�\u001a���=v�\'"�ʒGl��dX\'*��ӞR�b;��Y^���؂\u0017O{��\u001b��\u000fa��\u0018\u0014��8")\u0006m�\u001f�\u0007h����\u000ev96v�7G\u001f�vw��\t��J�i�U\u001a\u0018�(�7����Nζz@�G�p��iȲ,���\u000b\u0004po3��\u0018���\'i�`�(�S�]��P�Eˋ\u0013���\\�\u0007u�\nMЍ5\u0007w~�qhϜ�~E�\u0007OKp\u001f���l\u0003�\u0011~o\u000b����p\u0004m��X]�Uu�\u000b
```

Comment: Possible you can find answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017589/node-js-deflate-gzip-response-text

Comment: thanks @vanadium23 but It did not help me either..

Answer (score 2):

Without using any third-party libraries, and without attempting to detect the server's encoding:

```
var options = {
  hostname: 'www.example.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/deflateable-thing',
  method: 'GET'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  deflate = zlib.createDeflate();
  res.pipe(deflate);
  deflate.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('data: ' + chunk.toString());
  });
});

req.end();
```

The standard [`zlib`](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) library provides other stream handlers such as `gzip` too.

Answer (score 0):

Well... first of all you will need to know... whether the API produces a Raw-Deflate or a Deflate. Also, a lot of different choices can be made while deflating. You will have to be aware of the configuration used while Deflating. I assume you should be able to find them in the documentation of the API that you are consuming.

Lets assume the API to be producing a Deflate with default settings ( https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_options ) for now.

Now...

```
var zlib = require( 'zlib' );

// lets assume you have your response from api in a string variable
var responseDeflateString = "response from api";
// convert it to a buffer ( as you provided, its a utf8 string)
var responseDeflateBuffer = new Buffer( responseDeflateString );
// now inflate the buffer
// Note 1 : zlib.inflateSync takes another argument "option" and this will
//          depend upon how this API service was deflating, and should be added 
//          based on API documentation. For now we are using default options.
// Note 2 : its better to use the asynchronous version. But we are using
//          synchronous one for the sake of simplicity.
var responseInflateBuffer = zlib.inflateSync( responseDeflateBuffer );
// decode the buffer back to string ( utf8 )
var responseInflateString = responseInflateBuffer.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Request](https://github.com/request/request) support gzip parameter. Check out request [examples](https://github.com/request/request#examples)

```
var request = require('request')
  request(
    { method: 'GET'
    , uri: 'http://www.google.com'
    , gzip: true
    }
  , function (error, response, body) {
      // body is the decompressed response body
      console.log('server encoded the data as: ' + (response.headers['content-encoding'] || 'identity'))
      console.log('the decoded data is: ' + body)
    }
  )
  .on('data', function(data) {
    // decompressed data as it is received
    console.log('decoded chunk: ' + data)
  })
  .on('response', function(response) {
    // unmodified http.IncomingMessage object
    response.on('data', function(data) {
      // compressed data as it is received
      console.log('received ' + data.length + ' bytes of compressed data')
    })
  })
```